# C# - Keeping total number of correct guesses inside a variable

Tags: c#, coin-flipping

Beginner to programming & have been assigned a heads or tails coin flip project.

I've figured out how to make it randomly generate the number of requested flips and print out the answers. However, I'm supposed to have it add up how many times the user's input came up into the `correctCount` variable and I can't find anywhere how to do it. I've tried searching on here and different sites from searching throughout Google. I assume I need to take their string input and convert it somehow, like `if result == string`, then `correctCount + 1` basically, but can't figure out how to make that happen since you can't do that with `int` & `string`. Any info or hints would be very helpful - thank you!

````
    class Coin
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        // UserInput
        {
            Console.Write("Guess which will have more: heads or tails?");
            string headsOrTailsGuess = Console.ReadLine() + "\n";
  

            Console.Write("\n" + "How many times shall we flip the coin? ");
            int numberOfFlips = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() + "\n");


            // Declare variables
            int correctCount = 0;
            int heads = 0;
            int tails = 1;

            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++)
            {
                int result = rand.Next(0, 2);

                if (result == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Heads!");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tails!");
                }
 
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess, " + headsOrTailsGuess + "came up " + correctCount + " time(s).");```
````

Comment: You need to first convert your input string `headsOrTailsGuess` to something the computer can work with. Preferably an int or a bool, and then you can do the counting in the if statement.

Comment: Strictly speaking the instructions ask the user to input `heads` or `tails`.  The code then proceeds to evaluate for **H**eads or **T**ails.  Also, `int.Parse` will not work on non numerals which users *will* enter.  Use `TryParse`

Comment: I haven't ever seen `Console.ReadLine() + "\n"` and unless it is a super-secret-magical-trick, the `+ "\n"` part is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PMF mentioned, you have to not only receive user choice, but also analyse it.
A simple comparison should be more that enough here, although you might want to add some validation to user input.

```
static void Main(string[] args)

    // UserInput
    {
        int choice; //variable for parsed user choice
        Console.Write("Guess which will have more: heads or tails?");
        string headsOrTailsGuess = Console.ReadLine() + "\n";
        if(headsOrTailsGuess.ToLower().Trim() == "heads"){ //here you look if its heads
            choice = 0;
        }
        else{ //we can write additional if here to avoid other options from counting as tails
            choice = 1;
        }

        Console.Write("\n" + "How many times shall we flip the coin? ");
        int numberOfFlips = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() + "\n");


        // Declare variables
        int correctCount = 0;
        int heads = 0;
        int tails = 1;

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++)
        {
            int result = rand.Next(0, 2);

            if (result == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Heads!");
            } 
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tails!");
            }
            if(result == choice){ //comparing result to parsed choice and incrementing the counter
                correctCount++; 
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess, " + headsOrTailsGuess + "came up " + correctCount + " time(s).");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it using Linq.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         // UserInput
        {
            Console.Write("Guess which will have more: heads or tails?");
            string headsOrTailsGuess = Console.ReadLine();
  
            Console.Write("\n" + "How many times shall we flip the coin? ");
            int numberOfFlips = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() + "\n");

            // Declare variables
            List<string> resultList  = new List<string>();
            Random rand = new Random();
      
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++)
            {
                int result = rand.Next(0, 2);
                resultList.Add(result == 1? "Heads!" : "Tails!");
            }
            var guessCount  = resultList.Where(a=>a.ToUpper().Contains(headsOrTailsGuess.ToUpper())).Count();
            resultList.ForEach( a=> Console.WriteLine(a));
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess, " + headsOrTailsGuess + " came up " + guessCount + " time(s).");
            Console.WriteLine(headsOrTailsGuess);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System;

Console.WriteLine("Guess which will have more: heads or tails?");

var headsChosen = false;

var input = string.Empty;
do
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    headsChosen = input.ToLower() == "heads";

} while (input.ToLower() != "heads" && input.ToLower() != "tails");


Console.WriteLine("How many times shall we flip the coin?");

var flips = 0;

do
{
} while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out flips));

var rnd = new Random();

var heads = 0;
var tails = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < flips; i++)
{
    if (rnd.Next(0, 2) == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Heads!");
        heads++;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tails!");
        tails++;
    }
}

var userGuessed = (headsChosen && heads > tails) || (!headsChosen && tails > heads);

Console.WriteLine($"You {(userGuessed ? "guess" : "loose")}!");
```